# How to migrate NSWorkspace notifications to Swift 4?

Tags: swift, nsnotifications, nsnotification, nsworkspace, swift4

In Swift 3 I registered for sleep and wake notifications with this code:

```
let notificationCenter = NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.sleepListener), name: NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceWillSleep, object: nil)
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.wakeUpListener), name: NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceDidWake, object: nil)
```

but after migrating to Swift 4, I get this error after applying the suggested fixes:

```
Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'NSWorkspace'
```

How do I do this in Swift 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix this, you need to adjust the code referencing the notification's name from `NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceWillSleep` to `NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification`. The Swift 4 version is:

```
let notificationCenter = NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.sleepListener), name: NSWorkspace.willSleepNotification, object: nil)
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.wakeUpListener), name: NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification, object: nil)
```

You can see Apple's API diffs for this change [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1530075-willsleepnotification?changes=latest_minor).