# How to fix NotificationCenter in swift4

Tags: ios, callback, nsnotificationcenter, swift4

During conversion from swift3 to swift4 the convertor has changed `NotificationCenter` to the following view:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myController.myFunction(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSTextView.didChangeSelectionNotification, object: myNSTextView)
```

So, because of `selector` in `.addObserver()` myFunction now has @objc in front. Now the compiler is complaining, that the type `NSNotification.Name` has no member `NSTextView`. This is what convertor made, not me. I am confused.

How to fix this ?

**Update**. I have found the information here [How to migrate NSWorkspace notifications to Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402016/how-to-migrate-nsworkspace-notifications-to-swift-4)

So I have to use

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myController.myFunction(_:)), name: NSTextView.didChangeSelectionNotification, object: myNSTextView)
```

Comment: Watch the WWDC video “What’s New In Foundation” for information about the key paths implementation in Swift and how you can do observation with blocks/closures instead of callbacks. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Gary's comment, you need to switch over from calling the `Selector`, and instead use a callback. The following example shows what you need to setup for this to work.

```
var didBecomeActive: (Notification) -> Void = { notification in
    print("app became active")
}

private func setupNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: OperationQueue.main,
                                           using: didBecomeActive)
}
```

First, I create the var `didBecomeActive`, and made it a type of `(Notification) -> Void` to comply with what the function expects. In my example, I left the `notification` value in the callback, but if you are not using it, you can replace it with a `_` and it will work fine.

Next, instead of calling the function you use:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myController.myFunction(_:)), name: NSTextView.didChangeSelectionNotification, object: myNSTextView)
```

I call the following instead:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: <#T##NSNotification.Name?#>, 
    object: <#T##Any?#>, 
    queue: <#T##OperationQueue?#>, 
    using: <#T##(Notification) -> Void#>)
```

For the `using` param, just provide the variable you set up to receive the callback, which in this case is `didBecomeActive`.

Answer (score 0):

you may also type @objc before method and it will work